# \jot is assigned only inside document

Tags: preamble

The length `\jot` controlling the vertical space in align, etc. envs can be assigned only after `\begin{document}`. Can I do the assignment in some my sty-package file or in preamble?

Comment: In standard article class it can be set in the preamble.  Can you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: `\jot` is set to 3pt by the LaTeX format, even before the document class is read in; you're free to reset it whenever you want. There *might* be packages or classes that set it `\AtBeginDocument`, so without an example it's difficult to say something else.

Comment: Yes, you right. I forgot to mention that the problem comes from amsart-class.

Comment: Thanks to egreg! Your hint with AtBeginDocument solved the problem

Comment: I did like this

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\jot}{1.5ex}}

inside my package style file

Answer (score 6):

For the standard classes the parameter `\jot` has the value 3pt, which is assigned in `latex.ltx`. However, the `amsart` class adds the command `\@adjustvertspacing` to what's done by the size changing commands `\normalsize`, `\Small`, `\small`, `\large` and `\Large`.

This command does, among other things

```
\jot=\baselineskip \divide\jot by 4
```

So, since `\normalsize` is issued as part of `\begin{document}` actions, setting a value of `\jot` in the preamble will do nothing.

However, also issuing

```
\AtBeginDocument{\jot=5pt}
```

will not guarantee the setting is obeyed for the duration of the document, because a `\normalsize` declaration will change it again to the value set by the class. It's probably better to hook into `\@adjustvertspacing`. Say you want to set `\jot` to half the baselineskip instead of one fourth:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@adjustvertspacing}
  {\jot\baselineskip \divide\jot 4}
  {\jot=.5\baselineskip}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

If one third is preferred, use `\jot=.33333\baselineskip`.